# Inter App communication between apps present in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am building sdk which at point of time requires to communicate with third party app and communication broadly means here notifiying some event may or may not with any data.

I used `NotificationCenter` to do this but now I found somewhere written that it is for intra-app communication. And thats the behaviour I found when I run my code.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: action, object: nil, userInfo: jsonObject)
```

this is the listener I added in sdk

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onReceive(_:)), name: Notification.Name.ACTION_PAYMENT_ACK, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onReceive(_:)), name: Notification.Name.ACTION_PAYMENT_CMP, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onReceive(_:)), name: Notification.Name.ACTION_PAYMENT_REJ, object: nil)
```

I also found something written related to darwin notification but that was too old a post. How can I do inter-app communication.

I am looking for something like Broadcast in android.

Comment: Use custom Custom URL Schemes. It is very easy to use and you can find a ton of resources on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Inter app communication is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).
Since you want to do it without manual intervention, only the 2nd part, *Using URL Schemes to Communicate with Apps*, is relevant for you. It says

> A URL scheme lets you communicate with other apps through a protocol
>   that you define. To communicate with an app that implements such a
>   scheme, you must create an appropriately formatted URL and ask the
>   system to open it. To implement support for a custom scheme, you must
>   declare support for the scheme and handle incoming URLs that use the
>   scheme.

Comment: I want some thing that enable to and fro channel